# Zero stroke-width in SVG

Tags: svg, width, stroke

Having used Postscript for years, I am now learning SVG. There is a feature of PS that I have not been able to replicate so far: zero-width lines. In PS, a line with zero width is always visible: PostScript converts zero line width to the smallest printable width. On the screen, when zooming they never get any thinkness, yet are visible no matter the scale. I have used them when I wanted to render very thin lines, without worring about the final resolution I was going to use, and they turned out really useful.

However, in the official SVG docs (https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-strokes/) it says that:

> A zero value causes no stroke to be painted. A negative value is invalid.

Is there a way in SVG to build zero-width lines in the sense of PostScript?

Comment: Vector effect non-scaling-stroke perhaps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Robert said, the nearest thing to what you want in SVG is `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`.  This fixes the stroke width at 1 no matter how the SVG is scaled.

This works on Chrome and Firefox (and probably Opera - haven't checked), but AFAIK not IE/Edge.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80"
        fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
        vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>
```

Note that antialiasing will come into play depending on the position of the lines. The position **will** be affected by the scale.

If your lines are rectilinear (horizontal or vertical), you might also want to use `shape-rendering="crispEdges"`. This will turn off antialiasing for the shape on which it is used, resulting in sharp one-pixel lines.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80"
        fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
        vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" shape-rendering="crispEdges"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: @LeBeau thanks, not exactly the same but close enough!

Comment: Why doesn't this work in Firefox 90 and Chromium 91?

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Which part is not working for you?  I'm using Chrome 92 and FF 90 on Win10, and it's working as expected.

Comment: when I zoom the page (even this page when I run the code snippet), the lines change thickness.

Comment: If you are using the browser zoom, then yest they will change.  This feature only applies to SVG internal scale.